# How to debug QuotaSpecBinding for rate-limits in istio?

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I am trying to enable the rate-limit for my istio enabled service. But it doesn't work. How do I debug if my configuration is correct?

```
apiVersion: config.istio.io/v1alpha2
kind: memquota
metadata:
  name: handler
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  quotas:
  - name: requestcount.quota.istio-system
    maxAmount: 5
    validDuration: 1s
    overrides:
    - dimensions:
        engine: myEngineValue
      maxAmount: 5
      validDuration: 1s
---
apiVersion: config.istio.io/v1alpha2
kind: quota
metadata:
  name: requestcount
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  dimensions:
    source: request.headers["x-forwarded-for"] | "unknown"
    destination: destination.labels["app"] | destination.service | "unknown"
    destinationVersion: destination.labels["version"] | "unknown"
    engine: destination.labels["engine"] | "unknown"
---
apiVersion: config.istio.io/v1alpha2
kind: QuotaSpec
metadata:
  name: request-count
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  rules:
  - quotas:
    - charge: 1
      quota: requestcount
---
apiVersion: config.istio.io/v1alpha2
kind: QuotaSpecBinding
metadata:
  name: request-count
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  quotaSpecs:
  - name: request-count
    namespace: istio-system
  services:
  # - service: '*' ; I tried with this as well
  - name: my-service
    namespace: default
---
apiVersion: config.istio.io/v1alpha2
kind: rule
metadata:
  name: quota
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  actions:
  - handler: handler.memquota
    instances:
    - requestcount.quota
```

I tried with `- service: '*'` as well in the `QuotaSpecBinding`; but no luck.

How, do I confirm if my configuration was correct? the `my-service` is the kubernetes service for my deployment. (Does this have to be a VirtualService of istio for rate limits to work? **Edit: Yes, it has to!**)

I followed [this doc](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/policy-enforcement/rate-limiting/) except the VirtualService part.

I have a feeling somewhere in the namespaces I am doing a mistake.

Comment: i am trying using redis but its not working. could u help me?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56326044/rate-limiting-in-istio-using-redis-handler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define the virtual service for the service `my-service`:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: myservice
spec:
  hosts:
  - myservice
  http:
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: myservice
```

This way, you allow Istio to know which service are you host you are referring to.

In terms of debugging, I know that there is a project named [Kiali](http://kiali.io) that aims to leverage observability in Istio environments. I know that they have validations for some Istio and Kubernetes objects: [Istio configuration browse](https://www.kiali.io/features/istio-configuration/).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works now!

Comment: I am trying using redis but its not working.  could you help please. 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56326044/rate-limiting-in-istio-using-redis-handler