# Rate limits not limiting anything

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I'm trying to use the **istio rate limits** to limit access to the service *hello*.
(1 call per second max)
I used the template from the book info demo application.

This is the configuration I've got so far :

**Handler**

```
apiVersion: config.istio.io/v1alpha2
kind: handler
metadata:
  name: quotahandler
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  compiledAdapter: memquota
  params:
    quotas:
    - name: requestcountquota.instance.istio-system
      maxAmount: 1
      validDuration: 1s
```

**Instance**

```
apiVersion: config.istio.io/v1alpha2
kind: instance
metadata:
  name: requestcountquota
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  compiledTemplate: quota
  params:
    dimensions:
      source: request.headers["x-forwarded-for"] | "unknown"
      destination: destination.labels["app"] | "unknown"
```

**QuotaSpec**

```
apiVersion: config.istio.io/v1alpha2
kind: QuotaSpec
metadata:
  name: request-count
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  rules:
  - quotas:
    - charge: 1
      quota: requestcountquota
```

**QuotaSpecBinding**

```
apiVersion: config.istio.io/v1alpha2
kind: QuotaSpecBinding
metadata:
  name: request-count
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  quotaSpecs:
  - name: request-count
    namespace: istio-system
  services:
  - name: hello
    namespace: default
```

**Rule**

```
apiVersion: config.istio.io/v1alpha2
kind: rule
metadata:
  name: quota
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  actions:
  - handler: quotahandler
    instances:
    - requestcountquota
```

*Needless to say that curling the service's ip is still working even when its well over 1 request per second and the limit is activated...*

FYI, I used the serviceIP / virtualService (+ gateway).
Also I'm using the "In Memory" version and not the Redis version.

Any help on understanding where the error is would be gladly appreciated !

Comment: did it worked for you? i am trying redis but not working

Comment: @Forkmohit Nope... Still hoping that someone will point out where the problem is.

Comment: for memquota u can see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51707928/how-to-debug-quotaspecbinding-for-rate-limits-in-istio

Comment: @Forkmohit I think I have already tried this. Not sure... I'll give it a try when I have time. Thanks !