# Rate limiting in Istio using Redis Handler

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I am trying to apply ISTIO rate limiting using Redis Handler using [Redis Handler ISTIO](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/istio/istio/release-1.1/samples/bookinfo/policy/mixer-rule-productpage-redis-quota-rolling-window.yaml)

But mixer is not able to find the redis handler. Below from mixer log:

> 2019-05-27T11:59:23.910183Z   warn    Unable to find a handler for action. rule[action]='quota.rule.istio-system[0]', handler='redishandler.istio-system'
>
> - redisquota: could not create a connection to redis server: NOAUTH Authentication required.''.
>   Also, how to provide Redis credential for the template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

redis quota does not support Authentication

```golang
    // test redis connection
    option := redis.Options{
        Addr: b.adapterConfig.RedisServerUrl,
    }

    if b.adapterConfig.ConnectionPoolSize > 0 {
        option.PoolSize = int(b.adapterConfig.ConnectionPoolSize)
    }
```

[https://github.com/istio/istio/redisquota.go](https://github.com/istio/istio/blob/36eaeeec4b0fbb0bdf421d0aae81019f68c4840d/mixer/adapter/redisquota/redisquota.go)